# Qual a diferença entre o gravity e o layout_gravity no Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Na personalização das propriedades do layout no Android Studio notei que existe o `gravity` e o `layout_gravity`, ambos tem o nome `gravity`, então estou meio confuso quanto as suas funcionalidades.

Ou seja, quais são as diferenças entre o `android:layout_gravity` e o `android:gravity`?

Como cada um pode ser usado, e *quais os efeitos visuais* que suas propriedades podem causar no layout da aplicação android?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A diferença está a quê se refere a *gravity*.

- `android:gravity` - Posiciona o conteúdo da *view* em relação a ela.
- `android:layout_gravity` - Posiciona a *view* em ralação ao *layout* que a contém.

Esse efeito pode ser facilmente verificado com um *TextView*:

- `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` - Centra o texto horizontalmente, dentro da caixa de texto
- `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` - Centra a caixa de texto horizontalmente, dentro do *layout*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Imagem retirada desta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190050/2556111) no SOen.

A mesma resposta refere alguns aspectos que se deve ter em conta:

- `layout_gravity` não tem qualquer efeito num *RelativeLayout*, use apenas em *LinearLayout* e *FrameLayout*.
- `gravity` e `layout_gravity` não tem efeito se usar `wrap_content` para as dimensões do *TextView* ou do *layout*.

Comment: Com a imagem entendi melhor o funcionamento, assim da pra saber exatamente o resultado esperado, grato por adicioná-la.

Comment: Todos o créditos para o Suragch pela sua resposta no SOen.

Answer (score 2):

A diferença é que:

- android:gravity configura a gravity da View que você tá usando - como deve ser alinhado os elementos dentro dessa view;
- android:layout-gravity configura a gravity da View em relação ao seu parent- especifica como essa view deve ser alinhada em relação a View parent.