# Posicionar o texto no centro

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho este TextView:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

gostaria que o texto fosse centralizado verticalmente e horizontalmente em relação à área preta, que é o background do próprio TextView, que defini o `height` de `100dp`, o que preciso fazer?

Comment: Já tentou `android:gravity="center"` ?

Comment: eu estava usando layout_gravity. Deu certo! tks

Comment: Blz. Deixei uma resposta um pouco mais explicativa sobre a questão.

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre o gravity e o layout_gravity no Android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157408/2541)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para centralizar o conteúdo, basta utilizar o atributo `gravity` ou o método `setGravity`

**No XML:**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myId"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:text="Hello World"
   android:gravity="center" />
```

**No Java**

```
TextView text = findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
text.setGravity(View.Gravity.CENTER);
```

> A diferença entre **android:layout_gravity** e **android:gravity**, é que no primeiro, ele vai posicionar o elemento, no caso o **[TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)**; Diferente do segundo que irá posicionar o conteúdo do elemento.

Answer (score 0):

A propriedade será a `layout_gravity`, mas dependerá do tipo do `layout` que está usando, ou até se irá utilizar direto no elemento, por ex. um textView, então ele também deverá estar alinhado ao seu layout, com o `gravity`.

Por exemplo, um dos mais usados que é o `LinearLayout` na orientação `vertical`, você precisa usar o alinhamento inverso, ou seja, `center_horizontal`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="br.com.seuprojeto.Main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Se quiser saber mais especificadamente dessa propriedade:
[Android - Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)