# Como colocar margin dentro de uma caixa de texto ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android-studio

Olá! Queria adicionar bordas dentro do meu EditText, entretanto, o que é digitado fica bem colado com o contorno. Quero colocar uma espécie de padding ou margin pra dar distância entre a borda e o texto.

Código da forma:

```
<size
    android:height="40dp" />
<stroke
    android:color="#000"
    android:width="0.5dp"/>
```

Código do EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Digite seu nome" />
```

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso tem de aplicar um *padding* e não um *margin*.

*Margin* - Posiciona a view em ralação aos elementos circundantes.

*Padding* - Posiciona o conteúdo da view em relação a ela

O mesmos se aplica a `android:gravity` e `android:layout_gravity`.
Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157410/2541) mostra a diferença entre os dois.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada!!